# Python -- If a lock is acquired in a thread, are all variables in this thread locked?

Tags: python, multithreading, pthreads, locking

```
import threading

v = 0
lock = threading.Lock()

def increment():
  global v
  v += 1
  lock.acquire()

def decrement():
  global v
  v -= 1

thread1 = threading.Thread(target = increment)
thread2 = threading.Thread(target = decrement)
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
print(v)
```

This code prints 0，thread2 works normally.
Thread1 obviously acquired the lock, why can thread2 also manipulate the global variable v?

Answer (score 1):

Acquiring a lock does not prevent anyone from accessing anything. It is just a contract that critical parts of code can check if they are allowed to access an object. This must be implemented in your code. Simple example:

```
# Thread 1
lock.acquire() # blocks if someone else locked first
# access "protected" object here
lock.release() # give someone else the opportunity to lock


#Thread 2
lock.acquire() # blocks if someone else locked first
# access "protected" object here
lock.release() # give someone else the opportunity to lock
```

So for your example and with using a contextmanager to automatically lock and release the lock you get something like:

```
import threading

v = 0
lock = threading.Lock()

def increment():
    global v
    with lock:
        v += 1

def decrement():
    global v
    with lock:
        v -= 1

...
```

Comment: Can it be understood this way: variables have no relationship with locks. If a thread acquires a lock without releasing it, this thread or other threads are blocked if they want to acquire the lock.Rely on this method to achieve so-called thread safety.

Comment: Exactly right. The variable(s) and the lock do not know of eachother. Also variables do not belong to one thread or another (at least in this case).

Comment: If this has helped you, consider accepting the answer as correct to show the question as closed for others.